# Scraping site that requires Javascript enabled with Mechanize + BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, mechanize

So.. i got this site I am tryign to scrape, but as I understand lack of support of
mechanize for .js, and a stuborn site that requires javascript enabled browser is
not a good mix...

I am looking for ideas, on how to do this...

URL : https://members.iracing.com/membersite/login.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do, you could use [webkit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtwebkit.html) to parse the page, which will allow you to get the final html after the javascript has been executed. You could then use any decent html parser, beautifulsoup for example, to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, i actually started using Selenium RC, and i am able to fully control a instance of firefox with no problems. Its a bit slow, but i can actually run a couple of these in parallel so that is atleast good...

<br> Python rocks :)

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript I use [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/) for simple websites and [Webkit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtwebkit.html) for more complex.